# working netgraph configuration for ipfw and ng_bpf on FreeBSD

Tags: networking, freebsd, ipfw

I'm trying to get a raw BPF bytecode packet filter working on FreeBSD using a combination of `ipfw` with `ng_ipfw`, `ng_bpf` and `ng_tag`.

However none of the documentation or presentations I can find include any complete working examples.  The `ng_tag` man page only shows the `bpf_prog` code for passing a non-matched packet back thru `ng_bpf` but not how to generate the correct hooks for the whole netgraph.

```
#!/bin/sh
cookie=41
tag=412
mtag_ipfw=1148380143        # IPFW-tagged cookie from <netinet/ip_var.h>

prog=$(./bpfgen | ./bytecode_to_ngbpf)  # generate BPF code here

ngctl shutdown ipfw:$cookie

ngctl -f- <<-__END__
  mkpeer ipfw: bpf $cookie filter
  name ipfw:$cookie CLASSIFIER
  msg CLASSIFIER: setprogram { thisHook="filter" ifMatch="match" ifNotMatch="notmatch" $prog }
  mkpeer CLASSIFIER: tag match tag_bad
  name CLASSIFIER:match TAGGER
  connect CLASSIFIER: TAGGER: notmatch tag_good
  msg CLASSIFIER: setprogram { thisHook="match" ifMatch="ipfw" bpf_prog_len=1 bpf_prog=[ { code=6 k=8192 } ] }
  msg CLASSIFIER: setprogram { thisHook="notmatch" ifMatch="ipfw" bpf_prog_len=1 bpf_prog=[ { code=6 k=8192 } ] }
  msg TAGGER: sethookin { thisHook="tag_bad" ifNotMatch="tag_bad" }
  msg TAGGER: sethookout { thisHook="tag_bad" tag_cookie=$mtag_ipfw tag_id=$tag }
  msg TAGGER: sethookin { thisHook="tag_good" ifNotMatch="tag_good" }
  msg TAGGER: sethookout { thisHook="tag_good" tag_cookie=$mtag_ipfw }
__END__

ipfw add 2000 netgraph $cookie udp from any to any
ipfw add 2010 allow log udp from any to any tagged $tag

sysctl net.inet.ip.fw.one_pass=0
```

This is my best guess, but all that happens is that any packet matching the `ipfw` rule that drops stuff into `netgraph` gets dropped.

The *intent* was to have inbound packets that match the BPF program get tagged with the `MTAG_IPFW` cookie and the desired tag, and that packets that don't match only get tagged with the former, and the packets that are being returned from the `ng_tag` module both get forwarded back upstream to the `ng_ipfw` module via the single instruction program `ret 8192` (`code=6, k=8192`).

Can anyone spot what's wrong, or point me at a complete online example of how to correctly tag a packet this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding a [non-tagging example](https://www.opennet.ru/base/net/ng_ipfw_ng_bpf.txt) (in Russian!) I've since managed to fix this myself, using a simplified version of the `ngctl` commands in my question that just returns non-matching packets directly back to `ipfw`:

```
ngctl -f- <<-__END__
  mkpeer ipfw: bpf $cookie filter
  name ipfw:$cookie CLASSIFIER
  mkpeer CLASSIFIER: tag matched tag_bad
  name CLASSIFIER:matched TAGGER
  msg CLASSIFIER: setprogram { thisHook="filter" ifNotMatch="filter" ifMatch="matched" $prog }
  msg TAGGER: sethookin { thisHook="tag_bad" ifNotMatch="tag_bad" }
  msg TAGGER: sethookout { thisHook="tag_bad" tag_cookie=$mtag_ipfw tag_id=$tag }
  msg CLASSIFIER: setprogram { thisHook="matched" ifMatch="filter" ifNotMatch="filter" bpf_prog_len=1 bpf_prog=[ { code=6 k=65535 } ] }
__END__
```